# can i pass Values from Active Directory to Outlook Profile?

Tags: active-directory, outlook, outlook-2007, gpo

I'm trying to automate the creation of Outlook profile per user in our company. can i simply tell the PRF file to get the necessary values from the AD? for ex. the values for the "DISPLAYNAME" will be the "LOGONNAME" declared in the AD and If possible I'm going to implement this thru GPO.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No, but you are free to retrieve the data from the AD explicitly in your code and build the PRF file your self.

Comment: sorry i don't quite understand what you are trying to say and yes i am building my own PRF file but i am adding the data manually per user, can you clarify how can i retrieve the data from the AD?

Comment: If you know where the data is stored, you can retriever it from AD using your favorite API or library. Are you sure your AD stores IMAP4 and SMTP settings? I know for sure that Exchange settings are in the AD, but I am not so sure about anything else.

Comment: i'm not trying to get any IMAP4 or SMTP settings what i want is the values that you can declare per user.. the AD user attributes for example. Last Name, First Name, Email, Address, Phone no. etc..